Lots of soft bounce errors on one email in an A/B test
I ran an A/B test using Journey Builder's Path Optimizer recently and one of the paths received thousands of soft bounces to the point that less than half of the emails were delivered.
The only change was the send time. This is a monthly newsletter and is usally sent at 10:30am and I tested it against a send at 7:30am. I duplicated the email so I could track the analytics separately, had the journey start at 7:30am, with one split having a 3 hour wait step before the email so it would be sent at the regular time.
The B path for the 7:30 send had all the bounces, the A path 10:30 send went out as usual.
This newsletter has gone out at 10:30am for over 5 years now. Could a simple change in send time like this cause so many inboxes to flag it? There were no content changes to the email a contact would see.

this would indeed be odd. have you analyzed the domain distribution of the bounces? have you analyzed the bounce messages? Both are tracked in _bounce dataview.

I think I've identified the issue, which raises another question. I picked up one difference between the two sends, the send with all the bounces was using the Default sender profile instead of the regular sender profile used for the send. I created a new step and didn't set this as well. What causes an email to bounce from the sender profile? This happens at my organisation with the default profiles, is it something to do with how they're configured?

In your comment you mention you changed Sender Profile, too. That is very plausibly the reason.
The sender profile defines the send address -
which includes the domain, which together with IP address is a main driver for deliverability;
You can find your Email sender reputation for both IP and domain, for instance, see e.g. https://www.talosintelligence.com/reputation_center
It is up to the receiving email service provider what they consider more relevant and how they weight the two.
What is it about domain:
A Sender Authentication Package is (should be) purchased per sender (sub)domain and should take care of things like DKIM (Domain Key Identified Mail) Signature. Lack of a DKIM signature could plausibly lead to soft bounces as it is - in short - an "industry standard" used to protect against fraudulent email.
So: Choosing the domain -> SAP being installed or not could be very relevant. Using a new ("unauthenticated") domain is very plausible to affect deliverability, negatively.
